# How to jump from one class which extends FragmentActivity to another class which extends AppCompatActivity using Intent in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class Destination extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener {

private Button m;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_destination);
    m=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);     //btn is id of BUTTON in activity_destination.xml 
    m.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent dh = new Intent(Destination.this, UserJourney.class);
        startActivity(dh);
      }
}

public class UserJourney extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
         //codes
}
```

**Problem I'm facing :**

I  have set Destination as Launcher Activity in my Android App, so whenever I run this app, it will show Destination Page completely. But once I click on the button, it will show a blank screen and then again Destination Page will be loaded.

Comment: I can't see any issue with the supplied code. Can you post the code of the `UserJourney` class?

Comment: I'm guessing that `UserJourney` has a problem in `onCreate()`. You should post your manifest and the code for `UserJourney.onCreate()`. Did you look in the logcat? Add debug logging to see how far it gets? Step through the code in the debugger??